# Image sequence handling in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, image-processing

I need to convert an image folder with unnumbered names, like:

```
11.49.18.204.jpg
11.49.28.205.jpg
11.49.38.220.jpg
11.49.48.220.jpg
11.49.58.235.jpg
11.50.08.250.jpg
```

`FFMPEG` only accepts numbered inputs. The original file names are important to me. So much that I plan to overlay them on the video feed. I think I need to use SRT subtitle input with text overlay option.

I would like to know how I can make this work.

For example, this will not work

```
ffmpeg -i *.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, apparently FFMPEG does support name globing, from [ffmpeg.org/wik](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

> ffmpeg also supports bash-style globbing (* represents any number of
>   any characters). This is useful if your images are sequential but not
>   necessarily in a numerically sequential order as in the previous
>   examples.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix/Linux, this bash script line will rename a directory of image files to a series of sequential names that will work with ffmpeg. Basically it creates an in memory buffer of all the existing filenames, and then loops thru each name, moving them to an incrementally numbered name (in the same directory.

```
x=1; for i in *jpg; do counter=$(printf %03d $x); mv "$i" img"$counter".jpg; x=$(($x+1)); done
```

Comment: if i understand, this will create a duplicate of each file in folder , as in a real copy? this will create a lot of mess. but might be an option

Comment: No, "mv" in unix renames a file. So there will only be one copy.

Comment: sorry, cant see how to use this. i want to keep the original file names. your one liner just renamed the entire folder. 
which was a dup so no harm done.  
but you should mention that as a disclimer. for the next guy.

Comment: apparently FFMPEG faq recondes your method  

http://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#toc-How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f
    even $(ls -r -t *jpg)

Comment: @yoshco - you need to cd to the directory where your jpg files are first. If your directory was renamed with the above script, it must have ended with .jpg. If you want to keep the files and make a copy to a new directory, you can change the "mv .." part to a copy, like this: cp "$i" yourNewDirectoryName\"$counter".jpg

Comment: its a valid answer, but i dont want to have to mv gigs of data just to rename them. btw, globbing doesn't seem to work for windows. and ffmpeg is picky about what jpg it likes. even on bleeding linux/arch.

the best approach for me would have support for reading a list of paths from a txt file. that would be awesome

Comment: @yoshco Regarding the pickyness, all images in the sequence should have the same frame size and pixel format (the console output will mention if they change). If they change it can result in weird timing or skipped images.